# multiple process triggered on linux

Tags: linux, solr

I have multiple entries of a process "solr" on linux. It is installed as service on system and I can see following entries:

1. Inside file rc.local

   ## Start solr on VM start-up

/sbin/service solr start

2. Also under following files:

file: rc1.d

entry: K29solr -> ../init.d/solr

file: rc2.d
  entry: K29solr -> ../init.d/solr

file: rc3.d

entry: S79solr -> ../init.d/solr

file: rc4.d

entry: S79solr -> ../init.d/solr

file: rc5.d

entry: S79solr -> ../init.d/solr

My question is will these multiple entries lead to triggering of multiple starting of this process solr?  Currently only one process is running but logs depict another process might have got triggered but just want to be sure is these entries could be reason. I am linux expert so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want this process to run regardless of the runlevel (rc.#). You should only need the one entry in rc.local.

Here is more information on runlevels and startup scripts:

https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/systems-management/8116-an-introduction-to-services-runlevels-and-rcd-scripts

Comment: so, if we have entry for a script in /etc/init.d directory, will it copy itself into rc.local, or it will be required to be done manually, or it should be only at one place?

Comment: According to info. here [link]http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html , looks like we only need entry in init.d and rest is taken care by OS. Feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

When the system starts, it finds the default run level from the /etc/inittab file.
It will then run any scripts that have symbolic-links in the relevant rc*n*.d directory.

If the symbolic-link starts with S it will pass "start" to the linked script, if it starts with K it will pass "stop" to the linked script.

That is why you will find mostly K-prefixed symbolic-links in the rc0.d and rc6.d directories, because runlevel 0 is shutdown and 6 is reboot.